# Parsing huge XML with non-forward cursor movement

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm creating a task to parse two large XML files and find 1-1 relation between elements. I am completely unable to keep whole file in memory and I have to "jump" in my file to check up to n^2 combinations.

I am wondering what approach may I take to navigate between nodes without killing my machine. I did some reading on StAX and I liked the idea but cursor moves one way only and I will have to go back to check different possibilities.

Could you suggest me any other possibility? I need one with commercial use allowance.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio.  In vs you can use xmlreader to read large files.

Comment: could you complete with: some quantities : how many nodes ? how big is the file ? have you coded something yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably consider reading the first file into some sort of structured cache and then read the 2nd XML document, referencing against this cache (the cache could actually be a DB - it doesn't need to be in memory).

Otherwise there's no real solution (that I know of) unless you could read the whole file into memory. This ought to perform better too rather than going back and forth across the DOM of an XML document.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be an XML database. These usually have good join optimizers so as well as saving memory they may be able to avoid the O(n^2) elapsed time.

Another solution would be XSLT, using xsl:key to do "manual" optimization of the join logic.

If you explain the logic in more detail there may turn out to be other solutions using XSLT 3.0 streaming.

Comment: Which XML database do you mean? For this use case (processing large amounts of XML nodes with join) I tried some open source XML databases like BaseX, eXist and Berkeley DB XML. They all were magnitudes slower than my own home grown solution (based on Nux, XOM and Saxon) with a simple file based index to access the first XML file's nodes while processing the second XML file.

Comment: Well, that suggests your join condition is fairly specialized and defeats the optimizers in these products, but since you've shown no code, it's hard to comment on that. Perhaps you simply failed to set up the right indexes?

Comment: Added to my answer the option to use XSLT, since if you're prepared to do manual indexing then xsl:key makes it very easy.